# awk write in file with column separator

Tags: unix, awk

I am reading a file and writing first 2 columns into an output file.
I want write with "," as a column separator

I tried with

```
awk -F"," -OFS"|" '{print $1 , $2}' filename
```

The output file doesn't have | separator

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: By seeing your profile came to know you never select any answer as correct one, give it sometime and when you see few answers are there for your question then you could select an answer as correct one out of all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will not print since you didn't write it properly. Following are the 2 ways to mention `OFS` in any `awk` program.

1st way: By using `-v OFS="|"` mention it as a variable.

```
awk -F"," -v OFS="|" '{print $1,$2}' filename
```

2nd way: Use `BEGIN` section of `awk` for mentioning it(which is recommended too).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="|"}{print $1,$2}' filename
```

3rd way: As per ghoti's comment adding 1 more way of assigning value for `OFS` here. We could assign it before mentioning Input_file names too by doing this we could set different `OFS`  values for different Input_file(s)(since `awk` could read multiple Input_files so it can help in those kind of situations). Eg-->

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' FS="," OFS="|" Input_file1  FS=":" OFS=";" Input_file2
```

In above command for Input_file1 `FS` is `,` and `OFS` is `|` and for Input_file2 `FS` is `:` and `OFS` is `;`. Thanks to ghoti sir for mentioning this in comments :)

Comment: Nice answer as usual! ;-) +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Note that you can also do variable assignments *after* the script, as in `awk -F, '{print $1,$2}' OFS='|' filename`. The difference is that with this notation, the assignment is done in the order of files being read, that is it occurs after the `BEGIN` block has run.

Comment: @ghoti, yeah I was thinking that to write it too :) Thank for mentioning let me add that too now.

Comment: @ghoti, added the 3rd way with example now, kindly do let me know if you have any queries on same, thank you.